# Asymptotic directions on a parabolic set

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $\gamma\colon I\to S$, where $I$ is an interval and $S$ is a surface then the curvature restricted to $\gamma$ is $K(\gamma(t)))=0$ in the parabolic set $\gamma$, if we derive the
\begin{equation*}
dK_{(\gamma(t)}\cdot(\gamma'(t))=0
\end{equation*}
If $X\colon U\to S$ then $\gamma(t)=X(u(t),v(t))$, this implies that $\gamma'(t)=X_{u}u'+X_{v}v'$, characterizing the tangent vector $\gamma'(t)$ in terms of $dK_{(\gamma'(t))}$ we have:
\begin{align*}
    \nabla K_{\gamma(t)}\cdot\gamma'(t)&=0\\
    (k_u,k_v)\cdot\gamma'(t)&=0\\
    (k_u,k_v)\cdot(-k_v,k_u)&=0
\end{align*}
Assuming the parametrization is orthogonal. To verify that $\gamma'(t)$ is an asymptotic line when the normal curvature
\begin{align*}
    K_{n}(\gamma'(t))&=0\\
\end{align*}
that is, it is an asymptotic direction when the second fundamental form is zero.

I need help or suggestion on the following: I should show that in ordinary parabolic points $k_{n}(\gamma'(t))\neq 0$, that is, it is not an asymptotic direction.

In an ordinary parabolic point the direction is transversal to the set, which corresponds to a singularity of type fold.

If we want the point to be more generated, show that the direction is tangential to the set, which corresponds to a singularity of type cusp.

[image]

I have tried but could not solve it, it would be helpful to know what conditions or how to show this.

Comment: You did not define what the following are: $S$, $K$ (which kind of curvature?), parabolic sets, $U$, asymptotic direction, singularity of type fold. There is a huge lack of context. In other words, you did not define anything. I am a geometer and I do not understand your question. Also, $I$ is used as an interval and as the first fundamental form, which is quite confusing. I suggest you rewrite the whole question.

Comment: I agree with Didier that your question is not clearly written. However, I am quite familiar with this topic. I do not know your level and/or background, but you might take a look at [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Clint-Mccrory-3/publication/254205873_Cusps_of_the_projective_Gauss_map/links/00b4953711ecf92d91000000/Cusps-of-the-projective-Gauss-map.pdf).

Comment: @Didier 
I already edited it, maybe it's more specific

Comment: @TedShifrin  I already edited it, maybe it's more specific

Comment: You still have not given the correct definition of "an ordinary parabolic point." A *cusp* of the Gauss map is a critical point of the *restriction of the Gauss map to the parabolic curve*; an ordinary point is a non-cusp point. Where are you writing down the Gauss map and its restriction?